# Why are the relative paths in my local file got converted into absolute path?

Tags: javascript

I have a line of javascript like this:
`request.open('GET', 'data.txt', false);`
which should be pointing to the txt file in the same folder. However, when I preview the html from chrome and open the console, an "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" came out saying that I was use this path `file:///C:/Users/.../data.txt.` Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to start up a static file server, so that you can do a GET request to a relative path. Try [Fenix](http://fenixwebserver.com/). It's super easy to set up and even allows sharing your local file server outside of your network using localtunnel.me

Comment: So there is really no way to test these thing from a local environment?

Comment: @user3870240 Not if youre trying to do web requests to a local file.

Comment: @user3870240 seriously though, with fenix it will take you 5 minutes to select your folder with data.txt and your .html file and start a static file server on localhost

Comment: Ok, thanks,I thought there might be an build-in workaround.. Anyway, I tried Fenix, works like a charm. Thanks!